# How can I access the array element within a array element in Angular 9

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angular, angular8, angular9

Why I am not able to access an array within an array-like that in angular 9.
despite the console is also treating it like I have done in my code then why it is happening.

```
this.OptionsList[j].option = this.allQuestions[i].options[j].option;
```

screenshot

[image]

Comment: Mention the array in your post along with the element you want to access. A link with an example would be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by `not able to access`. Is it throwing an error or is the correct value not assigned to `this.OptionsList[j].option`? Because it looks like at the moment you are overwriting the values `this.OptionsList.option` property for each `allQuestions` iteration.

Comment: Can you actually the collection itself rather than a screenshot?

Comment: Yes it is throwing an error@MichaelD. **Question.html:305 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'option' of undefined**